# How to retrieve notification once I cleared them?

Tags: notifications

I swiped down from the top of my screen to view my notifications accidentally clicked on one that I didn’t get to see properly and then I clicked off it. I pulled down my notification screen again but the notification has gone as I accidentally “cleared” it.

Is there anyway to retrieve old notifications that have been cleared?

Comment: Deivice?  OS version?  Please add the necessary information by  [editing your question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/321750/edit).

Answer (score 2):

Notifications cleared from the notifications screen (swiping from the top down) cannot be retrieved.